# macOS - Is there a way to know which textfield triggered performKeyEquivalent?

Tags: ios, swift, tags, nstableview, nstextview

I have created a subclass of `NSView` and assigned that to the main ViewController's view.

I have two `NSTableViews` on that view. These subviews have `NSTextField`s.

I start editing one of these text fields and press `Cmd C`.

`performKeyEquivalent` is triggered.

How do I know which text field triggered it?

I haved added this line

```
override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
  super.performKeyEquivalent(with:event)
  let firstResponder = self.window?.firstResponder
```

but as expected it does not helper.

macOS tells me that firstResponder is a `NSTextView`, but I have no text view on the project.

`tag` does not helper either. I have the cells of my tableViews with tags equal to 100, 200, and 300 but

```
let tag = (firstResponder! as! NSTextView).tag
```

gives me `-1` (?)

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTextField` is a delegate of own editor, which is `NSTextView`, so here how it should go

```
override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {

    if let editor = self.window?.firstResponder as? NSTextView, 
       let textField = editor.delegate as? NSTextField {             
         print("Identified by: \(textField.tag)")
    }

    return super.performKeyEquivalent(with:event)
}
```